# How about the performance between PATINDEX and CHARINDEX?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

At all times I use `CHARINDEX` in stored procedure to check `NVARCHAR(MAX)` type of variable, but today I find that the `CHARINDEX` has an 8,000 byte limit!

I find this article [SQL CHARINDEX() Has Data Size Limitations](http://bennadel.com/index.cfm?dax=blog:966.view).

So I replace `CHARINDEX` with `PATINDEX`, but I do not know the performance between `PATINDEX` and `CHARINDEX`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) has limit of 8000 for the string you are looking for. Not for the string you are searching.

That article is probably wrong unless you want to look for strings > 8000/4000 length. However, it also uses text datatype which is deprecated. It's dated 2007, so it would be SQL Server 2005 or 2000 he used but SQL Server 2005 BOL does not mention 8000 at all and it's not something I've tried.

From the SQL Server 2008 BOL:

> CHARINDEX ( expression1 ,expression2 [
> , start_location ] )
>
> expression1  Is a character expression that
> contains the sequence to be found.
> expression1 is limited to 8000
> characters.
>
> expression2 Is a character expression to be searched.

Note: PATINDEX does not mention 8000 limit for SQL 2008 or 2005.

Finally, I'd use CHARINDEX because I think it's more intuitive for straightforward searches if you don't need pattern matching *and* it supports long strings

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I need handle a very long string(maybe more than 8000) so can only choose PATINDEX.

Comment: @gotqn: you can't really compare functions that do different things and behave differently. Saying that, PATINDEX is pattern matching where CHARINDEX is equality. It's comparing `LIKE` and `=`

Comment: @gbn, fair enough. I am completely agree with you, but in some situations you can use both of the functions to get what you want. For example, if you want to check if a word starts with some characters. Checking if the  word "SectionCategory123_moresymbols" starts with "SectionCategory" can be done with CHARINDEX('SectionCategory',word) and PATINDEX('SectionCategory%',word). So, which is faster? They could be translated in sql lover language to same things, or PATINDEX is better because it is checking for START symbols and will not scan the rest of the string?

Answer (score 1):

CHARIndex does have 8000-byte (not character) limit for the string you are searching, IF the datatype is text or ntext.  If the datatype is varchar(max) or nvarchar(max), the 8000-byte limit is not in effect; it searches the entire string.  (I was just bit by this.)  I resolved this just using CAST: `CHARINDEX(searchterm, CAST(columnname as nvarchar(max))`